# A simple question about a simple ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x}=0$. Rewritten as $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$ we instantly see the equation satisfying the ODE is $y=Cx$, which we would also get by separation of variables followed by integration, with $C$ the constant of integration.

The only constraint on the linear solutions in this case is that they must include the origin. If we decided to actually evaluate the ODE at any point on a function solving it, we would have $C-\frac{Cx}{x}=0$, but this equation becomes undefined at the origin, which happens also to be the only point in the plane required to be in the solution for $y(x)$.

My question: Is there a convention to ignore points where the ODE becomes undefined (if evaluated) so long as wherever it is defined the ODE is satisfied, even if $y(x)$ is defined at that point? It seems that the closest fitting function is $y=\frac{Cx^2}{x}$ in terms of being defined anywhere the ODE is defined. But that also seems like a silly solution compared to the linear one. Sorry this is such a basic question, but I'm trying to carefully check my understanding of how setting up simple ODEs affects the classes of satisfying equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all simply put  $\dfrac{y}{x}$ has the form $\dfrac{0}{0}$ but is well defined, no singularity at the origin, being equal to slope constant $C$.

This constant need not be *a priori* known, it can as well be a result of the subsequent integration process.

A  similar curve $y= \dfrac{\sin x}{x} $ has form $\dfrac{0}{0}$ at the origin which also evaluates similarly to $1,$ using the L'Hôpital's Rule.

Comment: I accept without understanding, am looking at calculus for the first time in 20 years and no longer remember why this would be, this question occurred to me in a first chapter on integration. If you cared to elaborate a bit, I'd appreciate it, though I'm sure this will make sense in a few chapters.

Comment: Next please read about L'Hôpital's Rule to evaluate indeterminate quotients/forms.